UIButtonConfiguration not working as expected
I created this button here to be an archive button for an inbox.
class ArchiveButton: UIButton {
    // MARK: - Initializer
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureButton()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configureButton()
    }

    // MARK: - Configuration
    private func configureButton() {
        self.configuration = createButtonConfiguration()
        styleButtonAppearance()
    }

    // MARK: - Button Configuration
    private func createButtonConfiguration() -> UIButton.Configuration {
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()

        // Set the image
        configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "archivebox")
        configuration.imagePadding = 12

        // Set the title and subtitle
        configuration.attributedTitle = TextStyle.header3.attributeString("Chats.Hidden.Inbox.Title.Archive".localized)
        configuration.attributedSubtitle = TextStyle.caption1.withColor(.herTextGray).attributeString("Chats.Pagination.Hidden.CTA.Description".localized)

        // Content alignment and spacing
        configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 0, bottom: 12, trailing: 0)
        configuration.titleAlignment = .leading

        return configuration
    }

    // MARK: - Button Appearance
    private func styleButtonAppearance() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.herDividerGray.cgColor
        self.backgroundColor = .herWhite
        self.tintColor = .herBlack
    }
}


For english, this looks good:

But for other languages like Japanese, the image icon is shifting over to the left:

I tried messing with this UIButtonConfiguration some more but there doesn't seem like a lot I can configure. Is there not a way to prevent this shifting icon? I tried the imageReservation value that looked most promising.
But the image reservation value didn't do anything besides add more space to the right of the image and also pushes the text OUT of the UIButton.

